# Scanner(System.in) - how to cancel/skip input waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I am just wondering how to control console inputs in separate threads?
I have thread A and thread B and thread C; B and C they both control user input... the thing is I am not pretty sure how to switch between B and C threads the `scanIn.nextLine();` because B seems to loop two unnecessary iterations before thread C can interrupt B :(

Main thread:

```
  public class Main
        {
            private volatile ThreadGroup threadGroup=new ThreadGroup();//contains concurrent hash map...
            private volatile TaskManager taskManager=new TaskManager(threadGroup);
            private A a=new A(threadGroup);
            private B b=new B(threadGroup,taskManager);
            private C c=new C(threadGroup);


     Main()
    {

      b.start();

      threadGroup.add(a,"A");
      threadGroup.add(b,"B");
      threadGroup.add(c,"C");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){new Main();}

        }
```

TaskManager method snippet:

```
...
public synchronized void threadCMaybeCanBeStartedLater()
{
      this.getThreadGroup().get("A").start(); 
}
...
```

thread A code like a *(overridden run method invokes)*:

```
public void loopIt()
{
   Random generator = new Random(); 
   A: while(!this.interrupted())
{
   Thread.sleep(1000);

   int i=generator.nextInt(100)+1;
   int j=generator.nextInt(100)+1;
   if(i==j){this.invokeC(); System.out.println("event : i==j");}

    }
 }

private void invokeC()
{
  if(!this.getThreadGroup().get("C").isAlive())this.getThreadGroup().get("C").start(); 
}
```

thread B code like a:

```
public void loopIt() throws InterruptedException
    {


        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        B: while(!this.isInterrupted())
        {

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            String command= scanIn.nextLine();
...

         if(command.equals("a"))
        {   
            System.out.println("a was entered");
            this.getTaskManager().threadCMaybeCanBeStartedLater();//             
            continue;
        }
        if(command.equals("b"))
        {   
           System.out.println("b was entered");            
           continue;
        }
        if(command.equals("c"))
        {
            System.out.println("c was entered");
            continue;
        }
        else{System.out.println("no such command");}

    }

}
```

thread C *(the run method invokes)*

```
public void loopIt() throws InterruptedException
        {
            getThreadGroup().get("B").interrupt();

            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

            C: while(!this.isInterrupted())
            {

                Thread.sleep(1000);

                String command= scanIn.nextLine();
    ...

             if(command.equals("d"))
            {   
                System.out.println("d was entered");             
                continue;
            }
            if(command.equals("e"))
            {   
               System.out.println("e was entered");            
               this.interrupt();
               break C;
            }
            if(command.equals("f"))
            {
                System.out.println("f was entered");
                continue;
            }
            else{System.out.println("no such command");}

        }

       getThreadGroup().get("B").start();

    }
```

...as you can see, the major code conception (see A thread snippet) is "*you don't know **when** thread C can be started but when it started you need to give it console*"; that's all; if it was GUI there was no problem but console-like app makes it quite problematic...

So the question is ... how to interrupt/re-start thread B immediately from thread C in this case?

Thanks

Comment: I think you posted `A` twice.

Comment: I have no idea what the point of this code is.

Comment: Oh my... it is obvious; The code is testing an ability of some incoming event 'injection' (in this case Thread A plays the role) ; If something happens in thread A then it takes console from thread B for thread C; the major problem there is no ability to inject the event because Scanner blocks forever or something :( I actually suspect the System.in static nature as well but I am not sure... So maybe I shouldn't use Scanner and there is an alt console input solution or maybe there is a more optimal way to control user input...

Comment: you can try the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130822/is-it-possible-to-interrupt-scanner-hasnext/19131235#19131235] where i have fixed (worked around) the problem with interrupting `System.in` read operation not being able to get interrupted unless user presses enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Synchronising Threads Using Thread Class**

1. **Thread.interrupt() on its own does not *synchronise* logic & timing between two threads**.

   **Thread.interrupt()** signals that the caller would *like* the thread to interrupt at a time in the near future.   The interrupt() method sets an interrupt flag.  The isInterrupted() method checks whether this flag is set (& also clears the flag again).  The methods Thread.sleep(), Thread.join(), Object.wait() and a number of I/O methods also check & clear this flag, when throwing InterruptedException.

   The thread doesn't immediately pause but continues running code.  The internal thread logic is designed & implemented by the developer: continue to run thread code considered atomic/urgent until it gets to an "interruptable point", then check the interrupted flag / catch InterruptedException & then do a clean pause - usually via **Thread.sleep()**, **Thread.join()** or **Object.wait()**, and sometimes by exiting **Thread.run()** altogether thus stopping the thread permanently.

   While all of this is happening the calling thread is still running and will execute an indeterminate amount of code before the interrupt takes effect... hence the lack of synchronisation.  There is a lack of guaranteed **happens-before condition** between the code in one thread and code in the other thread.
2. Some approaches that *do* synchronise logic & timing between two threads (creating a **happens-before condition**):

   - thread1 calls Thread2.join()
   - thread1 calls SomeObject.wait() and thread2 calls SomeObject.notify()
   - Synchronise on a method or block

**Quick Review of Your Code:**

1. Thread B runs in an infinite loop - there is no call to interrupt it from any thread and no call for it's thread to wait().  It will, however, temporily block until System.in has more input, and then continue.
2. Thread A only interrupts itself - cleaner and easier to analyse logic if you don't call `this.interrupt()` and `while(!this.isInterrupted())`: just change the while loop into:  `do { .... } while (i != j)`
3. Thread A only interrupts itself - cleaner and much easier to analyse logic if you don't call `this.interrupt()` and `while(!this.isInterrupted())`: just change the while loop into:  `do { .... } while (!"e".equals(command))`
4. Thread C must make the following calls at the top of it's while loop:

   ```
    threadB.interrupt();
    synchronized(this) {
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
   ```
5. Thread B must make the following call as the last line of code:

   ```
    synchronized(threadC) {
            threadC.notify();
    }
   ```
6. Reading from I/O (`nextLine()`) is a blocking & interruptable operation.  Right next to it you introduce `Thread.sleep()` which is also a blocking & interruptable operation that introduces an artificial delay in your code - it is not necessary; remove.
7. The only Scanner method you call is `nextLine()`.  You're using it as if it were an InputStreamReader & not doing any scanning.  Also, you're not buffering input.  If code stays like this, replace '`Scanner scanIn = Scanner(System.in)`' with:  '`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))`'.
8. The only `ThreadGroup` method you call are `add()` and `get()`.  You're using it as if it were a `HashMap` & not doing any thread group management.  If code stays like this, you may replace '`ThreadGroup`' with '`HashMap`'.  However, even the HashMap seems excessive - could simply pass Threads references to other Threads using constructors/setters and avoid HashMap altogether.
9. Avoid excessive use of `continue` inside loops - try to avoid altogether.  Best to do this by chaining successive '`if`' statements together using '`} else if {`'...
10. Potential race condition between main thread and thread B.  When thread B is started (from `Main()`) it may execute many lines of code before the main thread executes any more code - B may call ThreadGroup.get() before main thread has called ThreadGroup.add() x 3.  Solution: in Main(), put b.start() after ThreadGroup.add() x 3
11. In general, `"a".equals(command)` is better practice than `command.equals("a")` - it handles nulls, giving correct result without NPE (you seem lucky here - probably won't have nulls).

**Suggested Changes:**

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {

    ThreadC threadC;

    public void setThreadC(ThreadC threadC) {
        this.threadC = threadC;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.loopIt();
    }

    public void loopIt() {
        Random generator = new Random(); 
        int i, j;
        do {
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {                
            }
            i=generator.nextInt(100)+1;
            j=generator.nextInt(100)+1;
        } while (i != j);
        threadC.start();
    }

}
public class ThreadB extends Thread {

    ThreadA threadA;
    ThreadC threadC;

    public void setThreadA(ThreadA threadA) {
        this.threadA = threadA;
    }
    public void setThreadC(ThreadC threadC) {
        this.threadC = threadC;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.loopIt();
    }

    public void loopIt() {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String command = null;
        // loop until interrupted
        try {
            while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                command = reader.readLine();
                if ("a".equals(command)) {   
                    System.out.println("a was entered");
                    if (threadA.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                        threadA.start();
                    }
                } else if ("b".equals(command)) {   
                    System.out.println("b was entered");            
                } else if ("c".equals(command)) {
                    System.out.println("c was entered");
                } else if ("z".equals(command)) {
                    System.out.println("z was entered");
                    throw new InterruptedException("Command z interruption");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("no such command");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
        // Now notify ThreadC - it will wait() until this code is run
        synchronized(threadC) {
            threadC.notify();
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadC extends Thread {

    ThreadB threadB;

    public void setThreadB(ThreadB threadB) {
        this.threadB = threadB;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            this.loopIt();
   }

    public void loopIt() {
        // Block until the lock can be obtained
        // We want thread B to run first, so the lock should be passed into Thread C constructor in an already locked state
        threadB.interrupt();
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                // Put this thread to sleep until threadB calls threadC.notify().
                //
                // Note: could replace this line with threadB.join() - and remove  
                // from threadB the call to threadC.notify()
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String command = null;
            while (!"e".equals(command)) {
                try {
                    command= reader.readLine();
                    if ("d".equals(command)) {   
                        System.out.println("d was entered");             
                    } else if ("e".equals(command)) {    
                        System.out.println("e was entered");            
                    } else if ("f".equals(command)) {
                        System.out.println("f was entered");
                    } else if ("z".equals("command")) {
                        System.out.println("z was entered");
                    } else { 
                        System.out.println("no such command");
                    };
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite interesting. Thank you. You suggest architecture changes but I don't see the thread A supposed modifications; I mean 'how thread A should start thread C (the invokeC() method) in a more optimal way then according to the newly suggested modifications' or you mean the thread A code should be unchanged? As you can see, the basic conception is thread B gets command "a" to switch on 'thread C random starting timer' (the thread A plays as a random starter) so it is the most interesting point; so could you give more details please

Comment: ThreadA is interesting. I am just wondering how do you suggest to put all parts together with the main thread then?

Comment: See my review comments.  Unfortunately, I can't write every single line of code for you.  :^)

Comment: I understand :) I am just don't get are the ThreadA and ThreadC (see ThreadB snippet) volatile in the main thread or not for example? And I am thinking... you suggested stop ThreadA when i==j but what if "I would like NOT TO stop it when i==j? and make it NOT TO stop itself but always loop and react somehow on i==j?" I mean to make ThreadA a some kind of endless "event listener"? The event occur in my test case  "when i==j"... I've edited the ThreadA snippet to clear the conception

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` does not respond to interruption.  You want to do something like

```
String command;
if (scanIn.hasNextLine())
    command = scanIn.nextLine();
else
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: I know that; I mean how to interrupt/re-start thread A immediately from thread B?

Comment: @user592704 I'm not sure what you're asking, then.  Are you saying that you can't control precisely when B's call to interrupt A gets noticed?  That's the nature of concurrency.  You'll need to use locks or `volatile` or some other construct if you need them synchronized.

Comment: No I can control when to interrupt but the interruption comes not at once :( ... when B calls something like mythreads.getA().interrupt() sure : 1) A 'maybe still' sleeps 2) A is waiting for input 'so I input' 3) and only then A is interrupted and B takes the console :S The thing I want thread A work as it is untill I need thread B to take console. So you saying I must synch some points ? give more details please

Comment: Did you try my answer? It sounds like it is what you are looking for.  In your example, A is waiting for input when it gets the `interrupt()`.  Because scanner doesn't watch for interruption, it will block *forever*.  When you press `enter`, control jumps to your `while` condition and it notices the interruption.  The solution to this, as I posted, is to not block waiting for input.  Try my solution and then explain how it doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: yes, you are right. It seems like scanner is blocking forever or something so it pretty hard to have two scanIn.nextLine(); invoke at a time so that's why I ask how to close 'cancel' it manually or something :)

Comment: @user592704 Right.  But like I said, there *is no way to cancel*.  Once you call `nextLine()`, you are stuck.  The solution is to not call it unless you know that it will not block.  Which is what `hasNextLine()` does.

Comment: Oh... But I thought there should be a way like a close() method invoke or something? :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28074/discussion-between-user592704-and-nathaniel-waisbrot)

Comment: I've edited my question to give more details; watch it please

Comment: I've added comment; watch it please

Comment: I've edited my question to give more details; watch it please

Comment: @user592704 I continue to believe that my original answer is the correct one. I'm sorry you don't agree, but unless you've tried my solution and can explain in detail how it does not solve your problem I have nothing else that I can offer you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag variables (as global variables) to control the `while loop` in each thread...

suppose that Thread A has an infinite loop like this

```
while(true)
 while(x == 1){
   your code ...
 }
  Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

when Thread b is started you can change x to 0 (suppose x is a global variable) then when Thread b finishes executing change x to 1 at the end of Thread b code...

or you can interrupt the thread from thread itself based of flag value `x`