# Is it possible to interrupt Scanner.hasNext()

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I've got a thread that reads user input and sends it over the network. The thread sits in a loop like this:

```
sin = new Scanner(System.in);

while (sin.hasNextLine()) {
    if (this.isInterrupted())
        break;

    message = sin.nextLine();

    // do processing...        
}
```

But when I try to interrupt the thread it doesn't exit the `hasNextLine()` method.

How can I actually quit this loop?

Comment: maybe for this situation a do,while loop would make more sense. just  skip the first iteration and as condition do.. while(sin.hasNextLine() && !this.isInterrupted())

Comment: But it doesn't solve the problem - the thread is still blocked in hasNextLine() call...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the the `sin.hasNextLine` with the method below.
The idea behind is not to enter a blocking read operation unless there is data available on that stream.

I got the same problem a while ago and this fixes it.
Basically, when you perform `System.in.read()` on a thread and from another thread you try to interrupt it, it won't work unless you press `Enter`. You might think that pressing any character should work, but that is not true, because it seems that the read operation inside os (or the jvm's hardware abstraction layer) only returns full lines.

Even `System.in.available()` won't return a non-zero value unless you press `Enter` as far as i know.

```
private boolean hasNextLine() throws IOException {
    while (System.in.available() == 0) {
        // [variant 1
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread is interrupted.. breaking from loop");
            return false;
        }// ]

        // [variant 2 - without sleep you get a busy wait which may load your cpu
        //if (this.isInterrupted()) {
        //    System.out.println("Thread is interrupted.. breaking from loop");
        //    return false;
        //}// ]
    }
    return sin.hasNextLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. But anyway, it seems awkward, I can't believe there's no cleaner way

Comment: For `System.in` i haven't found other way around. But given that is a low performance operation (reading from console) it is fine for having that `sleep`. Additionally you can increase the value to 50 or 100, an see if it affects your operation somehow. I suppose it won't.

Answer (score -1):

My testing does not seem to support your findings. It is working as expected!

I wrote the following demo code

```
public class DemoThread extends Thread {

    Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (sin.hasNextLine()) {
            if(this.isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Thread is interrupted.. breaking from loop");
                break;
            }

            String message = sin.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Message us " + message);

            // do processing...
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        DemoThread thread = new DemoThread();
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        thread.interrupt();

    }

}
```

and the output is

```
a
Message us a
s
Message us s
asd
Thread is interrupted.. breaking from loop
```

So please check again. Also if you are confused with output asd it is the string input from the previous loop iteration at the point of which thread was not interrupted. If you don't want that you can do

```
if(!this.isInterrupted()) {
    String message = sin.nextLine(); 
}
```

---

```
Why is this happening?
```

Lets say in a iteration thread is not interrupted so it enter the while loop(hasNext() passes because of the String read in previous iteration).It check whether thread is interrupted(lets say it is not at this point of time) and goes to next line(scanning new string from stdinput). Now lets say the thread is interrupted. Your program will wait till you enter some string(for which you have to press enter in console). So even if the thread is inetrrupted string will be read and this string will be used to evaluate hasNext() operation(which will evaluate to true) and the context will enter the while loop.Here it will see thread is interrupted and will break.

**To avoid this you need to read string inside if(!this.isInterrupted()) statement.Refer to my code above.**

Comment: what java/os are you using? the thread does not get interrupted unless you press enter on the keyboard (for this `System.in` example). Basically you would want to interrupt it without user to press enter.

Comment: When you interrupt the thread all that happens is that the interrupted flag gets set. The thread does not exit the hasNextLine method early.

Comment: to csoroiu: yes, I have the same behaviour

Answer (score -1):

Usually if you want to have a thread running for a indefinite amount of time, but still be able to interrupt it, you'd do it like this:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: the thread does not get interrupted unless you press enter on the keyboard (when using System.in as input for scanner). Basically you would want to interrupt it without user to press enter.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a boolean and then set it to false when you want to stop the while loop

```
sin = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean = runLoop = true;
while (sin.hasNextLine() && runLoop) {
    if (this.isInterrupted())
        break;

    message = sin.nextLine();

    // do processing...        
}
```