# Clear Scanner(in)

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner, system.in

on my code, I've a long loop of sequential operation.
I make a thread to stop this loop manually.
Basically

```
private static void sendAndCheck() throws InterruptedException {

        stop = false;

        StopChecker r = new StopChecker();
        Thread t = new Thread( r );

        if ( vettore != null ) {
            t.start();
            for ( int i = 0; i < vettore.length; i++ ) {

                do {
                    if ( stop == true ) {
                        break;
                    }

                    //Do something for a lot of time.. (code deleted)

                } while ( !status.equalsIgnoreCase( "PROCESSED" ) ); //<- normal exit 
            }

            //Stop the thread
            stop = true;
        }

    }
```

and the thread basically is waiting on the standard input for stop character

```
public class StopChecker implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "1 - to stop" );
        while ( !Risottometti.stop ) {
            String command = scanner.next();
            if ( command.equalsIgnoreCase( "1" ) ) {
                Risottometti.stop = true;
            }   
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that, if the loop exit normally, the thread is locked on the scanner.next, so, the next input is lose inside the still dead thread.
How to release the scanner.next from main class?
I've tried with scan.close() but doesn't work...

There's another way to stop the loop, without kill the application? i try with keyListener, but i've got a null pointer

Comment: is `stop` `volatile`?

Comment: stop is "public static boolean"

Comment: Maybe this issue with sincronizity may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958228/scannersystem-in-how-to-cancel-skip-input-waiting

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983065/how-to-interrupt-java-util-scanner-nextline-call

Comment: @Lele - change `stop` to `volatile` and try.

Comment: thanks to @JaimeRey !! I edit the code adding ConsoleInputReadTask and interrupt the thread, and all work fine! Thanks!

Comment: `command.equalsIgnoreCase( "1" )` what is the uppercase version of "1" and what is the lowercase version? :P

Comment: @Tom 1 it's only temporaneous paramether XD after became exit XD XD

Comment: Ok :D. It just looked kind of funny :P.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with scan.close() or scanner.close()?

Comment: Yes, I've tryend, but it still waiting.
I solve with comment of @jaime Rey

Comment: @Lele You shouldn't close that scanner if you intend to read more user input later.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case where using `Thread.interrupt` is a valid occasion. Once the processing is successful, do a `stopChecker.interrupt` - that should fail the `Scanner.next` with a `ClosedByInterruptException` exception. Note that according to javadoc `System.in` might be closed because of this operation.

If that is not an option, the only solution is to not to use `Scanner` and do your option read in a non-blocking way.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code as follows.

1) Replace while loop with do - while block

2) Change Scanner code as follows

```
 do{
    while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
         String command = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("line:"+command);
    }
 } while ( conditionFlag)
```

When the condition is false, call

```
scanner.close();
```

Comment: `scanner.hasNext()` is always true of the scanner reads from `System.in` and that stream isn't closed.

Comment: But I am closing the stream outside of while loop once the thread has been stopped

Comment: "once the thread has be stopped" and when should that happen if the thread stays in the `while` lopp? And since you're closing the scanner you also make it impossible to read more user data later.